# Not getting right results using two tables with same limit

Tags: mysql, sql

1)I have four fields like material no, item no,quantity in one table and Date in other table

Input:
First table: res6

```
Material   item               quantity  ordnum
     101     91                 4         2
     101     92                 6         5
     101     93                 4         4
     102     97                 5         8
     103     98                 3         7
```

Second table: res7

```
   Date             item    ordnum
   2020-05-11        91       2
   2020-05-11        92       5
   2020-05-11        93       4
   2020-05-11        97       8
   2020-05-12        98       7
```

Requirement is we need to consider date as reference

2) If date is repeated twice or n number of times , the output should goes to first item with adding quantity.

Output:

```
    Material  item       date            quantity    ordnum
      101       91      2020-05-11           14        2
      102       97      2020-05-11            5        8
      103       98      2020-05-12            3        7
```

I have used below query:

```
SELECT material, reqdate, SUM(quantity),
(
    SELECT item 
    FROM res6 in_tab1, res7 in_tab2
    WHERE in_tab1.material = out_tab1.material AND in_tab2.reqdate=out_tab2.reqdate
    LIMIT 1) AS item
FROM res6 out_tab1, res7 out_tab2
GROUP BY material, reqdate;
```

But quantity is not adding up .. Please help

Comment: What is relation between 2 tables? and also, what is ordering logic in table 1?

Comment: SELECT res6.ordnum,
res6.item, res6.quantity,
  res6.material,
  res6.pdate,
  res7.ship "reqdate”
FROM res6,
  res7
WHERE res7.ordernum = res6.ordnum
AND res6.item     = res7.item
AND pdate           IS NOT NULL;          This is query which we are using output should be sum of quantity and it should goes to first item if req date is duplicate

Comment: req date means date which is in another table

Comment: Replace your table-like sample data with its CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Do NOT skip columns (may skip non-unique indices and foreign keys to non-listed tables).

Comment: I didnt get ur point

Comment: Your sample data is not matching with your explanation. Please provide correct sample data and your expected output from them.

Comment: I have provided pls check

Comment: How you keep 91 from 91,92,93 for Material 101?

Comment: yes first item which came is 91 so it should goes to 91 thats why I have use limit 1 in query

Comment: why is there are 97 item in the output if they are all of the same date. By your textual description it should only be 91.

Comment: we need to consider reqdate and material if you see for same req date different material will be there then output should go to 102 material which has item 97

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There is no way of establishing first item based on the sample data - unless you can say that the lowest order number should be used..

Comment: You can get your results with a relatively simple aggregation query on the first table.  The question is not clear on why the second table is needed, although it has this enigmatic condition:  "If date is repeated twice or n number of times, the output should goes to first item".  There is no "first" item, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: This is not clear yet that what is your logic to define first item among initial 4 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below script

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=148ef2792a1aa96c6126c5a2ec32540a)

```
SELECT Material,Date,
MIN (res6.item) Itemm,
SUM(quantity) quantity,
MIN(res6.ordnum) ordnum 
FROM res6
INNER JOIN res7
ON res7.ordnum = res6.ordnum 
AND res6.item = res7.item 
AND Date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Material,Date
```

Updated script below as per your comment-

[DEMO 2 HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8722f8d2d6fa5ed725b6dd2842ef726)

```
SELECT B.Material,
(SELECT item FROM res6 WHERE Material = B.Material AND ordnum = MIN(A.ordnum)) item,
A.DATE,
(SELECT SUM(quantity)  FROM res6 WHERE Material = B.Material) quantity,
MIN(A.ordnum) ordnum
FROM res7 A
INNER JOIN res6 B ON A.item = B.item AND A.ordnum = B.ordnum
GROUP BY B.Material,A.DATE
```

Final query based on your comments. You are just missing  defining the joining conditions

[DEMO 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9652bac77d47e3d2cb83b4bd182ce8e)

```
SELECT material, reqdate, 
SUM(quantity), 
( 
    SELECT in_tab1.item 
    FROM res6 in_tab1, res7 in_tab2 
    WHERE in_tab1.material = out_tab1.material 
    AND in_tab2.reqdate=out_tab2.reqdate LIMIT 1
) AS item 
FROM res6 out_tab1
-- Converted Joining as standard practice  
INNER JOIN res7 out_tab2
ON out_tab1.item = out_tab2.item  -- Missing
AND out_tab1.ordnum = out_tab2.ordnum  -- Missing
GROUP BY material, reqdate
```

Comment: sorry , It should not include min(item) beause sometimes item will be first it comes 95, 2nd time 92 , 3rd time 97, 4th time 91 ... but it should goes to first item number i.e; 95 thats why I have used LIMIT 1.

Comment: @RojaSimple please check my second query meet your requirement or not.

Comment: I am getting error like " Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: The requirement is we dont need to consider ordnum . We need to consider " date, material," If date is duplicate then it should goes to first item which is coming and add quantity . Is that possible to write java code , I think sql query will helps and feasible solution as well. pls suggest

Comment: Then how you will consider which order is the first one? you at least need some column to order by to pick the first row among one material number. @RojaSimple

Comment: You are getting the error as you have 2 same ordnum for 1 material number :(

Comment: This query is working fine for my requirement  "SELECT material, reqdate, SUM(quantity),
(
    SELECT item 
    FROM res6 in_tab1, res7 in_tab2
    WHERE in_tab1.material = out_tab1.material AND in_tab2.reqdate=out_tab2.reqdate
    LIMIT 1) AS item
FROM res6 out_tab1, res7 out_tab2
GROUP BY material, reqdate;"   This query everything good But SUM(quantity) it is displaying wrong quantity result.

Comment: @RojaSimple please check my final query in the answer.

Comment: The query is working fine but only duplicate reqdate but if there is no duplicate reqdate its showing item field as NULL

Comment: Please add sample data with all variety. Otherwise its difficult to help.

Comment: Not clear yet the logic that how you are defining the first item among 4 row belongs to material 101

Comment: As per query which you have given in demo 3 its working fine and mapping to first item as we are using LIMIT 1. But if req date is not duplicate then item showing NULL. Is it not possible to establish first item unless we mention item as ASC/DESC or ordnum as ASC/DESC.

Comment: As standard scripting, there should have a proper ordering for your requiremen.  Other wise there is no guaranty that you will always get the first row as first item. Limit 1 will not always return the same output except an appropriate ordering implemented.

Comment: I have discussed the same with team, there is no reference field which identifies first item. The idea is they suggested to read and store all the items of table based on material, quantity, date. If there is a new line matching with material, quantity , date of an existing item, it needs to add up the quantity of existing item. Is it possible please let me know.

Comment: @RojaSimple what is your MySQL database version?

Comment: sorry, I don't have idea because we don't have access to MySQL DB.

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.0 or newer you can try this- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=310fb314a1eed84ee6e203bf1a994544

Comment: In case of older version, try this- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7eb431816ca82e9629c3fdfb33d7bb5

Comment: It is going item no 93 for query which provided for older version. Newer version query is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

SELECT res7.date ,
       res7.item 
FROM  res7
INNERJOIN res6
        ON res6.item = res7.item
ORDER BY 
        res7.date[ASC/DESC]

Comment: The requirement is "We need to consider " date, material," If date is duplicate then it should goes to first item which is coming and add quantity"